# SCM for shared hosting

Tags: php, svn, version-control, shared-hosting

I have a sharing hosting, and obviously I don't have any SCM (Source Control Management) on it, but having to deploy every small changes here and there every now and then is frustrating.

Does anybody know a better way than using FTP or cPanel File Manager?

I would prefer not having to deploy every changed file manually.

The best solution would be to have some *free* SCM that I can run in a shared hosting, perhaps a PHP web application that does the same/similar thing to SVN

Comment: depending on your process - i find using winSCP with auto update remote quite handy, any change you make locally in any dir\file is automatically updated to the remote, you start it once, and it just sits in the background syncing changes.

Comment: Yeah, but I need the changes to be deployed ONLY if I'm sure all is fine, just like when I make a `commit` on my version then `update` on the server side

Comment: BTW: I don't understand why the close flags, can anybody leave a comment before/after flagging?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thank you very much @Dagon for the explaining :), but I think I've explained my problem as well as citing what I'm doing so far, but I guess this is not enough

Comment: there are some very cheap VPS options :-)

Comment: yes, I've been looking for some for a while already, and I'm interested to buy a service in the next couple of months, and I just felt like making the work easier until then as much as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`git-ftp`](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp): it allows you to use Git to manage your project *on your development machines* and use plain old FTP for deploying the changes to the shared hosting. `git-ftp` is smart to do only minimal transfers, delete files and directories when they are deleted in your repository etc.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion, git and mercurial are all free, can't get much cheaper than that and all support having hooks that will push changes, (by various mechanisms), to multiple locations.

Comment: Yes I know them and I'm pretty used to work with both git and svn, also I've been using svn for more than 5 years, but how can I use them in shared hosting? where should I install the server, and how do I update my hosted application?

Comment: Git and Mercurial are both hosted on every machine that they are on no server needed.  You can write a script that whenever you check in your changes, or tag them in a specific way, the script uploads your changes for you in exactly the same manner that you would do it by hand, e.g. ssh/ftp/etc. to both sites, n.b. providing that you have ssh or ftp login to your shared host you should be able to store the repository files there as well and be able to push files to the shared host.